# PutItem Error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: None

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Purpose: Uploading items into Dynamo using lambda function

However, I get this error:
PutItem Error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: NoneCode:

Code:

```
      try:
           for obj in list:
               User = obj["User"]
               Age = obj["Age"]
               Birthdate = obj["Birthdate"]
               Adult = bool(obj["Adult"])

               response = dyndb.put_item(
                   TableName='informationTable',
                   Item={
                       'User' : {'N':str(User)},
                       'Age' : {'N':str(Age)},
                       'Birthdate' : {'S':str(Birthdate)},
                       'Adult' : {'BOOL': Adult}
                    }
                )
                result = 'Put Succeeded'
       except Exception as err:
           result = format(err)
       return {
           'body': result
       }
```

Test JSON EVENT:

```
[{'User': '00000', 'Age': '114', 'Birthdate': '2022:08:01:17:2:50', 'normRange': 'True'},{'User': '10248', 'Age': None, 'Birthdate': '2021:02:01:13:2:40', 'normRange': 'True'}]
```

Error:
The first json object successfully uploads into dynamo
{'User': '00000', 'Age': '114', 'Birthdate': '2022:08:01:17:2:50', 'normRange': 'True'}

BUT, the second json object outputs an error:
{'User': '10248', 'Age': None, 'Birthdate': '2021:02:01:13:2:40', 'normRange': 'True'}

```
PutItem Error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: NoneCode:
```

Assumption:  From my understanding, Age is None, therefore when putting the item into dynamo its not fitting the criteria of a string. But, I do cast Age as a string. I need this value of Age to be None.

Comment: Posted an answer, did it work? if yes would mind to accept as a solution so that it helps others?

Answer (score 0):

You guessed it right. The problem is with the 'Age' Attribute. It might be a good idea to understand what kind of data type dynamodb supports (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html)

According to docs supported types are:-

- Scaler Types (number, string, binary, Boolean, and null)
- Document types ( Map and lists)
- Sets

`None` is not supported.

Even though you cast Age, it is still treated as `None`. There are other ways to deal with this situation

- as "None" string
- as an empty string
- don't save at all - remember, it is NoSQL database, attributes are not required

Or instead of `None` use `null` type https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/